Light diffusion through multiple transparent layers
I am trying to model a shadowbox but am struggling with getting the light to diffuse through the layers properly. It seems the light is traveling through each layer equally instead of losing strength as it goes so that the layers get more opaque the farther they are from the light source. I have attached screenshots of my material and light settings as well as what it currently looks like. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!




